# How can I group categorical variable that also meets another criteria in R? DPLYR?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a task that I can't solve. My goal is to be able to figure out how many "families" have children (under 18). I only need the sum of unique familyids and I've tried doing it in R and Excel and can't figure it out.

In my data I have four families and my data is saved on a client level.

```
data <- data.frame(
  
  "FamilyID" = c(10,10,10,11,11,11,12,12,13,13),
  "ClientID" = c(101,102,103,111,112,113,121,122,131,132),
  "Age" = c(26,1,5,35,34,1,54,60,17,21)
)
```

My goal is to have something like this

```
Metric                             Count
Families w/ Children                3
Families w/out Children             1
```

In my actual dataset I have thousands of families so I really appreciate ant help.
How can I do this with dplyr?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
counts <- data %>%
  group_by(FamilyID) %>%
  summarise(number_of_children = sum(Age<= 18), number_of_adults = sum(Age > 18)) %>%
  ungroup()

final <- counts %>%
  summarise("Families w/ children" = sum(number_of_children > 0), "Families w/o children" = sum(number_of_children < 1)) %>%
  gather() %>%
  rename("Metric" = key, "Count" = value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
data2 <- data %>% group_by(FamilyID) %>% 
   mutate(children=sum(Age<18)) %>% mutate(children=ifelse(children>=1,1,0))
data2 %>% group_by(children) %>% summarize(n_distinct(FamilyID))
```

which shows how many distinct Family IDs correspond to 0 children, and how many correspond to at least 1 child.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `any` to distinguish which families have children `TRUE/FALSE`, followed by `dplyr::count`

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(FamilyID) %>%
  summarize(have_children = any(Age < 18)) %>%
  count(have_children)

#------
  have_children     n
  <lgl>         <int>
1 FALSE             1
2 TRUE              3
```